# Sorting a file into several arrays (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am looking for some advice on how to go about this problem. I have a file (shown below) that contains a subject and then scores(this was created by user input from a different program). What I need to do is to store all of the scores into different arrays that correspond to the subject (ex. bioArray). I need help with formatting the input so that the buffer array only takes one line at a time and then the next time will turn the scores of the next line into an array. I am able to format the program that creates the scores to make them so that there is not a "/" between them if it can not be worked around while converting them to integer arrays. Thank you for your help.

```
Biology 2/3 11/12 15/20
Calculus 3/3 8/10  
Geography 2/3 4/5 1/2
Physics 5/10 5/5 4/6 7/8 9/9
Sociology 2/4 4/9 6/7
```

```
using std::ifstream;
    // Initializing the arrays
    int bioArray[50];
    int calcArray[50];
    int geoArray[50];
    int physArray[50];
    int socioArray[50];
    int bufferArray[50];

    // Declaring the variables that will be used
    std::string subject; // string to store the name of the subject

    ifstream infile; //opening the gradelog.txt file
    infile.open("gradelog.txt");

    if(infile.fail())
    {
        cout <<"unable to open ""gradelog.txt"". A file with scores needs to be present, called ""gradelog.txt"" " << endl;
    }
        int i;

        infile >> subject; //this stores the subject into a string, so it is not read into the array
        for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i) //gets input
        {
            infile >> bufferArray[i];
        }

        //after this I'll include code so that the contents of bufferArray are copied to 
        //the correct array name, such as "bioArray"

    // for loop for testing purposes
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) //reads the array for testing purposes, will be deleted
    {
        cout << bufferArray[i] << " ";
    }



    infile.close();
```

Comment: For clarification, I am assigning the current line to bufferArray, and then using the string, subject, to choose which array buffer array becomes

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you didn't have the `/`. Then you could just read the numbers directly without having to use `bufferArray`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, john. I changed the other program so that it just puts a space between scores.

Comment: read the tokens (eg: 2/3)  into a `std::string`, then split the string on the `'/'` into two `strings` and then convert the two strings into numbers. What you do with those numbers I'm not entirely sure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no `/` in the input then doing `getline` following by an `istringstream` buffer is the simple way to go.

```
#include <sstream>

std::string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    std::string subject;
    buffer >> subject;
    if (subject == "Biology")
    {
        int score;
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer >> score)
            bioArray[i++] = score;
    }
    else if (subject == "Calculus")
    {
        ...
```

Code would be even simpler if you used `std::vector` for `bioArray` etc.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out a lot. I was just wondering though, when i initialized the arrays, I put int bioArray[25] = {0}. This made the unfilled parts of the array are filled with zeros. Do you know any way to fix this?

Comment: @cmbtmstr Why's that a problem? But if you just write `int bioArray[25];` it won't happen.